# Invalid Operands to Binary Conversion for QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qtextstream

I need to know about the conversion for QTextStream to a bool variable. Have a look at my code :

```
QFile file(SOME FILENAME);
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) qDebug() << "FILE COULD NOT BE OPENED";
QTextStream stream(&file);

bool dBm = false;
if (!stream.atEnd()) stream >> dbM;
```

As my above expression is throwing the error for which I need help.

Comment: `QTextStream` has no overloaded `operator>>` for `bool` argument.

Comment: And it will help if you added the error in your question text.

Comment: Please don't paraphrase error messages. Use copy and paste.

Comment: it's not clear what a text file should print for a bool ("true"/"false"? "True"/"False"?, "Yes"/"No"?), so a generic overload doesn't make much sense to me, you could do `stream >> (dBm ? "true" : "false")`, or write a helper function doing this.

Comment: Yes, it prints true/false but as mentioned by you the ternary expression doesn't work.

Comment: **Please don't paraphrase error messages. Use copy and paste.** - seriously, include the error message you get from the compiler. We can't read your mind, and if people need to play 20 questions in order to help you, they will be much less inclined to do so. Finally, any future person that has the same issue may search using the error message... and find nothing (instead of any useful answer you may have gotten)

Comment: @CharonX, Actually I put the error message as my title of the question.

Comment: @SatishJoshi The question title might not be the best place to put the error message, especially if you leave no hint that the that is the error message you get. Secondly, got an answer and while you said "thanks it works now" you neither upvoted said answer, nor marked it as the accepted anwer (i.e. one that solved your problem)...

Answer (score 2):

There is no `>>` operator for `QTextStream` and `bool` out of the box.

The doc. of [QTextStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) mentions a lot of input operators but none for `bool`:

> QTextStream & operator>>(QChar &c)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(char &c)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(short &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(unsigned short &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(int &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(unsigned int &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(long &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(unsigned long &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(qlonglong &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(qulonglong &i)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(float &f)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(double &f)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(QString &str)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(QByteArray &array)
>   QTextStream & operator>>(char *c)

However, it's not that complicated to add one for the personal joy.

The most complicated about this is what [@Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931574/invalid-operands-to-binary-conversion-for-qtextstream#comment104122962_58931574) already mentioned in this comment – to define an adequate textual representation of `true` and `false`.

For my MCVE, I used simply `0` and `1`.

`testQTextStreamInputBool.cc`:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>

// a stream input operator for bool
QTextStream& operator>>(QTextStream &in, bool &var)
{
  char value;
  in >> value;
  var = value == '1';
  return in;
}

int main()
{
  QTextStream in(stdin);
  while (!in.atEnd()) {
    bool value; in >> value;
    qDebug() << "Read:" << (value ? "true" : "false");
  }
}
```

`testQTextStreamInputBool.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQTextStreamInputBool.cc

QT = core
```

Compiled and tested in `bash` of [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQTextStreamInputBool.pro

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQTextStreamInputBool.o testQTextStreamInputBool.cc
g++  -o testQTextStreamInputBool.exe testQTextStreamInputBool.o   -lQt5Core -lpthread 

$ echo "0110010" | ./testQTextStreamInputBool
Read: false
Read: true
Read: true
Read: false
Read: false
Read: true
Read: false

$
```

Of course, it would make sense to overload the `operator<<(QTextStream&, bool)` as well to have a matching custom output for the custom input.

If not, the compiler will convert the `bool` to `int`, implicitly, and use `QTextStream::operator<<(int)`. Hence, `false` will be written as `0`, `true` as `1`.

That's just what my overloaded bool stream input operator expects...